# JQuery Air DatePicker is empty when using a function onselect

Tags: jquery

When I add the Jquery below in my code, input #today appear empty and onselect functun works fine.
If I remove Jquery, input is not empty but function onselect doesn't work (this is normal...)
How should I have both input full and on select working.
It seems to become from my jquery code !?

I use [JQuery Air DatePicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/)

Php :

```
$myDate = date('d/m/Y');

echo '<input type="text" class="datepicker-here form-control" id="today" name="today" data-language="fr" value="'.$myDate.'"/>'
```

Jquery :

```
$('#today').datepicker({
  language: 'fr',
    onSelect: function onSelect(){
      var bl = $('#today').val();
showUser(users.value, bl, group.value);
console.log(users.value, bl, group.value);
    }
})
```

Comment: Might want to try using an ISO-8601 date (YYYY-MM-DD) rather than d/m/Y - the former is the format a native date input (`<input type="date" />`) would expect. Not familiar enough with the plugin you're using to guess at what it's expecting.

Comment: You may also want to specify the date format, as well: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-9

Comment: I don’t use input type date because it doesn’t works on safari... Maybe you know another way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Guess it is better to let the own lib deal with prefilling the current date, since it already has a proper method.

Also set your date format as an option, after the language.

```
$('#today').datepicker({
    language: 'fr',
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    onSelect: function onSelect() {
        var bl = $('#today').val();
        showUser(users.value, bl, group.value);
        console.log(users.value, bl, group.value);
    }
}).data('datepicker').selectDate(new Date())
```

From the docs: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/#sub-section-51

Functional example: https://codepen.io/th91vi/pen/xxZxMww